# ListView onscroll listener inside Nested ScrollView give wrong Last Item Visible

Tags: javascript, android, listview, android-nestedscrollview

Im trying this ListView inside a NestedScrollView and add the onScroll Listener to it but when i try to get listView.getLastVisiblePosition(), it gave me the max items of the list not the last visible. How to get the same result as when its just listview without NestedScrollView ?

I appreciate all kind of help, Thanks

my code for onScrollListener

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
     @Override
     public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {}

     public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
     {
                Log.d("scroll", "scroll: " + listView.getLastVisiblePosition());
     }
});
```

my xml for it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_merchant">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/ListView">
            </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

solution here :

*at least work for my case for now

**change from using listview.setonscrolllistener to nested.setOnScrollChangeListener

```
nest.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) 
            {
                //get current height of screen and total height
                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                final int stageHeight = display.getHeight();
                int currentheight = stageHeight+scrollY;
                int maxheight = listView.getHeight();

                Log.d("myarc","aaa "+ currentheight +" bbb "+ maxheight);
                if(currentheight>=maxheight && (update))
                {
                    //turn off autoupdate
                    update=false;
                    Log.d("myarc","masuk bro ");
                    //add new item
                    RowItem item = new RowItem(R.drawable.wp, "GG", "GGWP");
                    rowItems.add(item);

                    //refresh listview
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(listView);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Well, this is the expected behaviour. Since your list is contained in a scroll view, it is already fully expanded.

Comment: already find another solution, anyway thx @SelçukCihan

Comment: added code for what works for me :)

Comment: your 'NestedScrollView' code works for me :) Thanks